# foreach loop only dumping one variable

Tags: php, xml

I have the following code to find an xml element that matches preg_match

```
foreach($xml->Items->Item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion->Binding as $BookBinding) { //loop through the xml data to find the correct ASIN for the kindle edition
    foreach ($xml->Items->Item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion->ASIN as $Kindlestring)
    {
        var_dump ($BookBinding);
        if (preg_match('/Kindle Edition/i',$BookBinding))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

however it is only var_dumping the first loop of Binding, how come?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your data.  Do some basic debugging first.  Add some echo statements to see where your loop is failing.  Make sure error reporting is on.  Make sure that the XML object will actually let you iterate through the element you are trying to iterate on.

Comment: @Brad the loop is not even entering the if statement, I did an var_dump and it only gives me back the first value of Binding,

Comment: I guess you have only one item in xml?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to loop through sibling elements in that way. The inner loop is not referenced in the current version of your code, so perhaps you should remove it to make it clearer.

Comment: @user2349095 What is "hidden for privacy"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here because I don't know the structure of the XML but my guess is you're looping on the wrong part of the XML.  This is my guess on what you should do:

```
foreach($xml->Items as $item) {
    $bookBinding  = $item->Item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion->Binding;
    $kindleString = $item->Item->AlternateVersions->AlternateVersion->ASIN;

    if (preg_match('/Kindle Edition/i',$BookBinding)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Also it looks like there may be multiple AlternateVersions so you may need to do a nested loop like so:

```
foreach ($xml->Items as $item) {
    foreach ($item->Item->AlternateVersions as $version) {
        $bookBinding  = $version->AlternateVersion->Binding;
        $kindleString = $version->AlternateVersion->ASIN;

        if (preg_match('/Kindle Edition/i',$BookBinding)) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```